# JLabel + images

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jlabel

I'm applying an image to a JLabel using the command `.setIcon()` and then adding the label to a panel

```
public browser() throws IOException {
 JLabel lblimg;
 Image img;
 ImageIcon ico;
 img = ImageIO.read(new File("<FilePath>"));
 ico = new ImageIcon(img);
 lblimg.setIcon(ico);
 lblimg.setBounds(300,90,120,120);
 add(lblimg);
}
```

but this doesn't resize the image inside the label, this way just a slice of the image will appear if it is bigger than the label size.

Does anyone knows a method to insert an image to a label background, resizing the image into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method I wrote some years back to resize an image in Java.

```
public ImageIcon picturePrep(ImageIcon icon) {
    final int DESIRED_WIDTH = 880;
    double imageWidth = icon.getIconWidth();
    int imageHeight = icon.getIconHeight();
    imageWidth = DESIRED_WIDTH/imageWidth;
    imageHeight = (int) (imageWidth * imageHeight);
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    return new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(DESIRED_WIDTH, imageHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a BufferedImage and get scaled instance, set its width and height to the width and height to that of the label. Now if you even resize the label, the image will cover the label.

For Example: `lblimg.setBounds(300, 90, 300, 120);`

```
BufferedImage bimg =ImageIO.read(new File("file path"));
        ico = new ImageIcon(bimg.getScaledInstance(lblimg.getWidth(), lblimg.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        lblimg.setIcon(ico);
```

The following image has been scaled according to the label's width and height.

```
lblimg.setBounds(300, 90, 100, 50);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a appropriate layout manager to take care it for you automatically.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

If, for some bizarre reason, you can't use a layout manager, then you should probably be considering a solution based around custom painting, you could make use of the components preferred size to provide it better information when settings it's bounds

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("<FilePath>"));
JLabel lblimg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
lblimg.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(300, 90), lblimg.getPreferredSize()));
```

Then, you don't need to make guesses